# Sorting nodes in mutilivel tree

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures

I have a class which can be converted into tree structure.

```
public class Tree 
{
    public bool leaf { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool expanded { get; set; }
    public List<Tree> children { get; set; }
    public Tree()
    {
        children = new List<Tree>();
    }
}
```

children property in the class is a list of tree class which contains all the child nodes.

Every node can have multiple children and sub children.   Every node has sortOrder property  using which I want to decide the order in which node will appear at any given level.

For all the nodes for which leaf property is true (node which are the bottom of the tree) needs to be sorted based on SortOrder property with-in that level.

How can I sort data by using SortOrder Property for all levels.

Comment: where the nodes of your tree are stored? Do you have them in a list? As of it is now, I suppose that the children list holds the childrem of this node. Let A, B and C are the only nodes of your tree. let A be the root of the tree and B and C clidren of A. Then the SortOrder of A would be 0 and it's children would be a list of two elements {B, C}. Last the SortOrder of B and C would be 1 and their children collections would be empty. Right?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: Yes, children is the list which contains all the child nodes. Since the children list is of type 'Tree', every item in children can again have multiple children.

Comment: @Brown_Dunamite please post an example of what you have, an instance of your tree with a few nodes and then show us what you expect as output. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively order the leaf nodes by adding the following method to `Tree`:

```
public void OrderLeaves()
{
  children = children.Where(x => x.leaf).OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToList();

  children.ToList().ForEach(c => c.OrderLeaves());
}
```